# The “prickmouse” and the “butcher's broom”

Tags: etymology, old-english, german, italian

I sometimes go for walks in the wood near where I live; and in the undergrowth, beneath the oaks and pines, you'll find an evergreen prickly shrub which is called **[pungitopo](http://lnx.cainapoli.it/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Pungitopo.pdf)** in Italian. The word is derived from *pungere* (to prick) and *topo* (mouse). Its [cladodes](http://www.futura-sciences.us/dico/d/botany-cladode-50003221/), which are easily mistaken for leaves, are like those of holly.  In order to deter mice from eating their food supplies, it is said that country people would tie branches of *pungitopo* in a bundle  and hang them with the preserved meats (salami, dried sausages, capocollo etc.) from the rafters or ceilings.  As the bundle dried, the branches not only didn't lose their spiny ‘leaves’, but the spikes became sharper and deadlier.

[image: close up butcher's broom]

The Germans call it *Stechender Mäusedorn*, which I think is literally translated as “pricking mice thorn”. In English, the same shrub is called ***butcher's broom***. [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/butcher-s-broom) says the term first appeared between 1555–65 although the plant obviously existed long before then. Several sources claim that the branches of this plant were used by butchers to sweep their chopping blocks clean and recent research suggests that the plant also contains antibacterial oils.

If we look at the meaning and etymology of *broom* we find the following by Oxford Dictionaries and Etymonline.

> **broom**: A long-handled brush of bristles or twigs, used for sweeping.

Its [origins](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=broom) date back to the name of several types of flowering shrubs, called *brōm* in Old English.

> Old English ***brom***, popular name for several types of shrubs common throughout Europe (used medicinally and for fuel) and characterized by long, slender branches and many yellow flowers, from Proto-Germanic *bræmaz "thorny bush"
>
> As "twigs of broom tied together to a handle to make a tool for sweeping," mid-14c.

[image: Spanish broom in bloom]

Spanish broom (*Spartium junceum*) fits the description above, indeed its flowers are yellow, and its branches are long and slender but it looks nothing like the butcher's broom.

So was the 15th century *butcher's broom* originally called *holly*? According to Etymonline and Wiktionary, holly dates back to  *holin*, a shortening of *holegn*, and *holen* from Old English. And possibly derived from Proto-Germanic *hulisaz* (“butcher's broom, forest thistle, holly”)

[image: holly with berries]

The earliest citations I found of *butcher's broom* were in an English Italian dictionary, dated [1611](https://books.google.it/books?id=hcNMAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA390&dq=%22butchers%20broom%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVrfPi3rviAhVByKQKHZ0XAO8Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22butchers%20broom%22&f=false), and in a compendium of therapies attributed to the renowned French barber surgeon, Ambroise Paré, written in [1649](https://books.google.it/books?id=TzVbqmHLfGMC&pg=PA699&dq=%22butcher%27s%20broom%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdkZ-62LviAhXB0aQKHXm_BikQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22butcher%27s%20broom%22&f=false).

> …which have relation to the spleen: as, as Time, Epithymum, Broom flowers. Cetrach, Capers, the bark of their roots, the bark of Tamarisk. Diureticks, such as respect the kidnies and urinarie passages: as, the roots of Smallage, Asperagus, Fennel, **Butcher's broom**, the four greater cold seeds, Turpentine, Plantain, Saxifrage. Arthniticks, or such as strengthen the joints: as Cowslips, Chamepytis, Elecampane, Calamint, Hermodactils, and the like.

In Italy, I am not aware that *pungitopo* was ever used for sweeping floors as the grain, *[saggina](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/saggina/)*, in English “sorghum” or “broom corn/broomcorn” in the US, has been used to make brooms since the medieval.

[image: old fashioned handmade broom propped against a brick wall]

> Although the origin of broomcorn is obscure, sorghum apparently originated in central Africa. Production of this crop then spread to the Mediterranean, where people used long-branched sorghum panicles for making brooms in the Dark Ages. Broomcorn may have evolved as a result of repeated selection of seed from heads that had the longest panicle branches. The broomcorn plant was first described in Italy in the late 1500s. Benjamin Franklin is credited with introducing broomcorn to the United States in the early 1700s.
> *[NewCROP](https://hort.purdue.edu/newcrop/afcm/broomcorn.html)* Purdue University

As I was reading up on *pungitopo* and brooms in Italian, I came across the term *[bruschino](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1298&bih=647&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=H8zqXIiyN52X1fAPvu6YkAk&q=bruschino%20spazzola&oq=bruschino%20spazzola&gs_l=img.3...21712.22061..22605...0.0..0.69.137.2......0....1..gws-wiz-img.b4dMvqIJckE#imgdii=zExtJFQLozJXUM:&imgrc=uR3eHutUbwHiVM:)*, the diminutive form of *brusca spazzola*, a brush which can be used to either scrub the floors, wash the laundry or
for grooming horses. The Italian *bruschino* looks very similar to the English “brush”–a coincidence?

As you can see, I managed to rake together some information but I'm still itching to know a few other things.  Mainly...

- Were *holly* and *butcher's broom* called by the same name in Old English?
- English is a Germanic language, so why wasn't the plant called something like “prickly mouse”, “spiky mice thorn” or “prick-mice” like its German counterpart?
- Is there any evidence, in art or in literature, that the plant was actually used by *butchers* to sweep the cutting block (or floors) in their shops?
- Why is it a *butcher's **broom*** and not a *butcher's **brush***? A broom has a long handle and is used to sweep floors, a brush has shorter  bristles with a shorter handle.

Comment: Regarding your second question, plant names can be extremely different even between very closely related languages. Berries are found all over Scandinavia, for example, but they nearly all have completely different names in Danish, Swedish and Norwegian (which are **very** closely related). The fact that English is Germanic doesn’t imply that a particular little plant’s English name will be similar to its German name (cf. how in Spanish it’s called _rusco_ and in French _fragon faut-houx_ ‘fake-holly laurel’, or _petit-houx_ ‘little holly’).

Comment: Does the [OED’s entry on *butcher’s broom*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/25336) help at all? An 1847 citation reads: *The whole plant is gathered by butchers, and made into besoms for sweeping their blocks and shops; and hence it obtained the name of **butcher's broom.*** The oldest citation for the English term is from a 1538 treatise in Latin: *Humile officinæ uocant bruscum, angli **Butchers broome**, & Petygrew.*

Comment: @tchrist where is the 1847 citation from? Is it a dictionary entry? I have yet to find a citation where someone sees or uses that plant in a butcher's shop. Everyone *says* that it  was to clean the butcher's block but where is the actual "evidence"? It would be nice to see a reference that is not from a dictionary or anecdotal. I suppose the name is proof itself. P.S thanks for 1538 reference

Comment: The following source adds more color to its origin referring to the plague in Europe. https://books.google.it/books?id=XziTU2rZhKcC&pg=PT208&dq=%22butcher%E2%80%99s+broom%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwih8czo877iAhVDqaQKHSPoASg4ChDoAQhBMAU#v=onepage&q=%22butcher%E2%80%99s%20broom%22&f=false

Comment: @user240918 that's a lovely piece of trivia, thank you!

Comment: I think that the “butcher’s” story is true in the sense that they most  likely  used the plants not to simply clean but to disinfect the floor, blocks they worked on (think of the filth  and blood from dead animals). By sweeping the floor with those plants, the idea of a broom was a natural association.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's from *The Rural Cyclopedia* by Rev. John M. Wilson. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhZyy.png).

Comment: @tchrist ooh, I like that page. I have save it on my computer, it helped confirm that the name is not based on some urban myth. And it seem its older name was "knee holly", which is interesting too.

Comment: *English is a Germanic language, so why wasn't the plant called something like “prickly mouse”, “spiky mice thorn” or “prick-mice” like its German counterpart?* There are thousands of local names for local plants. There is no reason whatsoever that calling a plant “prickly mouse” in a small village in Bavaria would be thought of as a good name for the same plant by someone in The North of England. For example, within 20 miles of where I grew up, the common plant Cow Parsley was known as Wild Chervil, Queen Anne’s Lace, Deadman's Meat and Jack in the Hedge.

Comment: @Greybeard the bullets were my attempt to stir interest and answers that were more detailed than the one provided by Clive Goodhead. Seems like it failed.

Answer (score 4):

An important point relevant to this question is that the earliest meaning of the word "broom" in English, dating to **c1000**, referred to a particular species of flower.  It appears that "broom" as a botanical term in English was not a metaphorical extension of tools for sweeping, but rather the original meaning, figuratively extended to refer to the tool.

Per the *OED*:

> **A shrub**, *Sarothamnus* (or *Cytisus*) *Scoparius* (family Leguminosæ), bearing large handsome yellow papilionaceous flowers; abundant on sandy banks, pastures, and heaths in Britain, and diffused over Western Europe. Also the genus to which this belongs, and the allied genus *Genista*, including the White Broom, and Giant or Irish Broom cultivated in gardens, and many other species.

The *OED* proceeds to offer an extended definition that includes more plants as definition 2:

> Entering into the name of various other plants used for sweeping, or in other respects fancied to be akin to the broom proper; as *butcher's broom* **n.**, *Spanish broom* **n.**   (a kind of grass).

Note that in this context, "broom proper" likely refers to the plant [*Sarothamnus Scoparius*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cytisus), not "a utensil for sweeping things," which the word would come to mean later, first recorded in the 1400s.

Far more botanical brooms are discussed in modern texts, [including in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genisteae).

Because of this evolution of the word "broom," the *OED* makes only a passing reference to the specious etymology provided by *The Rural Cyclopedia*, edited by John Marius Wilson, which contains this excerpt on "butcher's broom."

> The whole bush is gathered by butchers, and made into besoms for sweeping their blocks and shops; and hence it obtained the name of **butcher's broom.**

The complete text from the journal [can be viewed here on Google Books.](https://books.google.com/books?id=cOIxAQAAMAAJ&lpg=PA550&dq=The%20whole%20plant%20is%20gathered%20by%20butchers&pg=PA550#v=onepage&q=The%20whole%20plant%20is%20gathered%20by%20butchers&f=false)

It seems notable that this citation is from **1847** whereas the term "butcher's broom" dates back to **1538** (and, as noted above, **broom** itself dates back to c1000), so the veracity of the *Cycolpedia*'s etymology shouldn't be assumed infallible.

Prior to offering the 1847 citation as comparative evidence, the *OED* makes its more primary etymological assertion:

> Apparently so called on account of the appearance and texture of the stiff, spiny tips of its leaves

---

### Long story short?

That long-handled implement that witches and wizards play Quidditch on was likely named after a kind of flower, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion here is that the transfer of the term to the utensil used for brushing is figurative. I suspect not. The plant was dried and used as a brush. Nothing figurative about it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There has certainly been a broadening; brooms with plastic bristles are now common. Such brooms only having an associative relationship with Cytisus and Genista (etc) species, the usage is figurative. Literal senses refer directly to the original sense of a word.